# ActiveX .cab installer doesn't work in Windows 7

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, windows-7, activex

i am trying to learn about activex and how they are deployed, so I download [this sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14533/A-Complete-ActiveX-Web-Control-Tutorial), created the .cab and signed it with my own certificate, then visited the html page that includes the .cab. When doing it on Windows XP it works fine and the "processing..." image is shown after installing the activex, but **in Windows 7, it doesn't install** and the "processing..." image never show up, neither when logged in as administrator, or as a normal user (ie ask for admin password when running the .cab).

**What could be causing this?**

Comment: 1. Share your markup. 2. Where is the page in question running? 3. Which version of IE are you using? 4. Are you logged in as an Admin or as a regular user?

Comment: @EricLaw What do you mean with markup? The page runs in localhost. Tested IE 8 and 9. Tried both regular user and admin.

Comment: Markup is the HTML or JavaScript you're using to invoke the object.